# How do I use HttpClient for Basic authentication & API Key header together

Tags: c#, rest, api

I have tried the same with HttpWebRequest its working fine but I need to use HttpClient for my program
So far I did following code but its returning unauthorised

```
        string baseurl = "http://xxxxx.net/";
        var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("myusername:mypassword");
        webclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
        webclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =  new AuthenticationHeaderValue("X-ApiKey", "=" + "5AB4374B-A5CF-4F7A-91FF-E5E893347C3F");
        webclient.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseurl);
        webclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        webclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

Comment: You are replacing the `webclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization` with the second statement.

Comment: Also your second statement is peculiar, why is the value prefixed with `=`?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is here:

```
webclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
webclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("X-ApiKey", "=" + "5AB4374B-A5CF-4F7A-91FF-E5E893347C3F");
```

The second one is overwriting the first, so the Basic authentication isn't happening. If you want to include an `X-ApiKey` header in the request as well as using Basic auth, then don't use `DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization` to set the `X-ApiKey` header. Instead use `DefaultRequestHeaders.Add`, which lets you add any HTTP header you want:

```
webclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
webclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-ApiKey", "5AB4374B-A5CF-4F7A-91FF-E5E893347C3F");
```

I removed the `"=" +` from the code since the `=` is added automatically. But if the `=` is actually part of your API key, then add it back.

Comment: Is there a reason you stripped out the `=`?

Comment: @DavidG I added an explanation of why. I assumed it was added as a misunderstanding, but maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

Still, I get the Unauthorized error but web request working fine

```
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.Headers["X-ApiKey"] = "5AB4374B-A5CF-4F7A-91FF-E5E893347C3F";
            String encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes("myusername" + ":" + "mypassword"));
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
```